# Android SDK: чтение мыла

Tags: android-sdk, android, eclipse

Скиньте статью или объясните, как можно проводить чтение эл.почты на Андроиде.

Желательно название библиотек и т. д.

Comment: через браузер можно =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот здесь ооочень подробное описание: [Sending Email in Android using JavaMail API without using the default/built-in app](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2033124/646857).

Чтобы получить доступ к определённому содержимому gmail смотрите здесь: [Android Gmail](https://developers.google.com/gmail/android/).